# How to read this message from text file?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a question about C# code

How to have this code read from a text file?

```
#Msg    10001
{   
This is message 
}
```

I want to  read text  Where ID is 10001 and read the  message written inside { }

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should *read* the text file with message, and then *parse* it

```
  // Reading the file
  String text = File.ReadAllText(@"MyMessageFile.txt");

  // Parsing: startIndex - index of the first '{' from the heading
  // that is  #Msg ... 10001   
  int startIndex = text.IndexOf('{', Regex.Match(text, @"#Msg\ *10001").Index);
  // stop index: closing '}'
  int stopIndex = text.IndexOf('}', startIndex);

  // Message is text between '{' and '}'
  // heading and trailing whitespaces (\n, \n, ' ')  removed
  String message = text.Substring(startIndex + 1, stopIndex - startIndex - 1).Trim(' ', '\r', '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example then I'll give you this:

```
using System.IO;
```

You must add this in. ^

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.ReadLine();

sr.Close();
```

Note: File must be located in the Debug folder of your project otherwise you will have to copy and paste the file path.

Also, please don't ask vague questions in this site or you may not get answers. Welcome to this site btw.